# I have a dynamic xpath which is based on 4 values, if I am using OR condition the xpath looks huge, any other way to handle this?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation, python-behave

Below is the XPath which substitutes the values given in the option variables.

```
_OPTION_1 = "Average"
_OPTION_2 = "M"
_OPTION_3 = "Casual"
_OPTION_4 = "D"

_WIDTH_VALUE_XPATH = f"//mat-option/span[contains(text(),'{_OPTION_1}')] | //mat-option/span[contains(text(),'{_OPTION_2}')] | //mat-option/span[contains(text(),'{_OPTION_3}')] | //mat-option/span[contains(text(),'{_OPTION_4}')]"
```

Answer (score 1):

While you could use `or` instead of the union operator `|` to shorten the xpath somewhat, if the goal is readability of Python code, you could use triple quotes to make the string more legible.

```
_WIDTH_VALUE_XPATH = f'''
//mat-option/span[contains(text(),'{_OPTION_1}')] | 
//mat-option/span[contains(text(),'{_OPTION_2}')] | 
//mat-option/span[contains(text(),'{_OPTION_3}')] | 
//mat-option/span[contains(text(),'{_OPTION_4}')]
'''
```